# ios iphone app - set value to a variable in init function

Tags: iphone, ios, init, setvalue, sdwebimage

I use sdwebimage and ktphotobrowser for my thumbnail gallery. because I have different galleries I need many sources. But i can't change the datasource in the SDWebImageDataSource.m file

I made a variable named `myStr` and now i want to get it in the SDWebImageDataSource's `init` function so i can get data from another source

Is it possible or may I have a change create another function named `initWithString` then pass my path to that function?

in my viewcontroller I initialize the SDWebImageDataSource as
`SDWebImageDataSource *sd = [[SDWebImageDataSource alloc]init];`
then i set variable
`sd.myStr=@"http://mypath.com";`

but I can't get the value of `myStr` in the `init` function of SDWebImageDataSource.m file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Init method, initialize your string by setting an empty string. This will solve your problem. or if you can manage to create custom method  [[SDWebImageDataSource alloc]initWithString:@"SOMESTRING"];will also be fine.

Comment: if i understand correctly you say: if i initialize my string as an empty string does my code work?

Comment: thanks i did with custom method [[SDWebImageDataSource alloc]initWithString:@"SOMESTRING"];